# What is the use of the master branch in git?

Tags: git

Say I have 2 versions of my library developed in parallel:

- 1.0
- 2.0

I end up with 3 branches:

- 1.0
- 2.0
- master

Am I wrong with my branches? Where should I commit new features of 1.0 and 2.0? For now, I commit each feature in its respective branch. And 1.0 bugfixes are commited in 1.0 branch and then merged to 2.0 branch.

What should contain `master`?

Comment: You can delete it if you want to. Or keep all the shared code of both versions in there. `master` has no special purpose, it's just the default branch for a new repository since you need at least one branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given all answers don't cite any source and all contradict themselves, I decided to follow [Doctrine's workflow](http://www.doctrine-project.org/contribute.html) (given I'm also developing a PHP library and Doctrine is a "modern"/recent project).

> The doctrine repository holds the following primary branches:
>
> - **doctrine/master** Development towards the next release.
> - **doctrine/release-*** Maintenance branches of existing releases. These
>     branches exist in parallel and are defined as follows:
>
> doctrine/master is the branch where the source code of HEAD always
>   reflects the latest version. Each released stable version will be a
>   tagged commit in a doctrine/release-* branch. Each released unstable
>   version will be a tagged commit in the doctrine/master branch.

In short, it's quite similar as the SVN workflow:

- **master** will contain the current developed release, which is 2.0 for me. Master is unstable!
- **1.0** will contain the stable release, branched from master once the version is released as stable.

I just don't know what I will do if I have a **3.0** version in development in parallel of 1.0 and 2.0 (a future experimental version). I think I will create a 3.0 branch and leave 2.0 on the master (given 2.0 is the "next" release).

Answer (score 2):

There is no right way or wrong way here. For some projects, it can be useful to think of master as the 'unstable' branch, so most of your development effort is focused there. (Usually it pays off to work on new features in their own branches and merge those to master). Now, with your version branches, you can easily merge or cherry-pick changes from master. Depending on how the project works, you might want a policy that says version branches should always be in a good state, and that any commit should increment the version number.

Having an unmoving master branch is quite handy because you can set up that branch *once* and expect git pull to always get you the latest code for the project.

Comment: I don't get how setting up the `master` branch once and not commiting/merging into it would mean it contains the latest code for the project? (you said "unmoving", do I understand it right?)

Answer (score 1):

`master` in a convention name for a branch where all "bleeding edge" code belongs. If you branched specific versions of your code it's okay - commit fixes to them, but evolve your code in master and then create branch from master with your version name.

Comment: I think its more common for master to contain currently shipping code and do bleeding edge development on feature branches.

Comment: In a "shippable" projects, yes. OP said that it is a library, so master should contain bleeding edge, and branches / tags for shipped versions. YMMV, I'm doing as I wrote. :)

Answer (score -1):

The master git branch is created default by git. It should include the latest **stable** release of your software product, or in other words, the branch you want users to download by default. You should commit experimental features to the v1 and v2 branches.

Comment: Can we have more reasoning for that? Because I don't see any arguments why prod branch would have stable version and master would be stable version of the app. btw i do use master as stable usually, but no one backs up that it can be don'e viceversa